# Software for handling estimates of new projects

Tags: project-management

As part of my job I frequently provide estimates for bids and new contracts. I'm quite comfortable with that and how to arrive at some (hopefully) sensible numbers. However, the tooling to support such a job is very limited. Currently it's all spreadsheets (sales has some really fancy ones), which isn't ideal. I've looked around for supporting software, but all I can find seems to target construction businesses. I'm however looking for something targeting estimating of programming tasks. Are there any better solutions out there than relying on spreadsheets?

Comment: A library could be filled with the books about such estimations. What is common in them: you need to give them input data. To provide this input data, somehow you need to model the project. Typically, some "meta-structure" is produced, and then the estimations are being done by matching their stats to the stats of previous similar projects.